# How to keep accelerometer values constant independent of screen orientation in android?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors

Sorry if the title is hard to understand, I don't know how else to phrase it.
Accelerometer data on android is relative to the screen's orientation and tilt (TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) I am trying to make an app in which accelerometer data is constant regardless of how the user is holding his device. I think I'd have to calculate angle of tilt from the gravitational force affecting the XYZ values and somehow go from there as well as use the compass to lock the X axis to north (or any other direction). Anyone have some ideas/tips?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to obtain and what do you mean with "constant value"?

Comment: There is a seprate sensor type that takes gravity and orientation into account and filters it out for you, it's calleed GAME_<something or other>..

Comment: Sorry, it's TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.  see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html